# Emulating a Scientific Workplace toollbar?

Tags: front-end, programming, notebooks

It is possible to have a notebook with the tools of the Basic Math Assistant palette in a toolbar similar to Formatting tool bar it already has? I would like it to work so when I open another notebook this toolbar appears by default.

I am looking for something similar to what the Scientific Workplace program provides.

Example:

[image]

I imagine there might be some command to modify the screen or notebook, but it escapes me.

Comment: To clarify: you want a selected *palette* to embed itself at the top of the notebook, and you want this to occur automatically every time a notebook is opened?

Comment: See `DockedCells`. They are exactly what you want. You can embed them in a stylesheet and just pick that stylesheet.

Comment: Linked topics should answer your doubts, let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @Myridium Yes, that's what I'm looking for, but my knowledge is not enough to do it, thanks for your time